# How to Disable Worklight Analytics logging

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-server

We are using MobileFirst 6.3 + Liberty 8.5.5 and we need remove this entry for the message.log file:

[11/12/15 12:00:21:808 ART] 00000108 SystemOut                                                    O com.worklight.analytics.api.AnalyticsHttpService.sendDataToURL target server response code: 201

It is increasing our log files a lot. I was reviewing other posts here and the Liberty logging options but these settings applied only for the trace.log file (if it is enabled).

Here is my current bootstrap.properties file:

websphere.log.provide=binaryLogging-1.0

com.ibm.ws.logging.max.file.size=1

com.ibm.ws.logging.max.files=10

com.ibm.ws.logging.console.log.level=WARNING

com.ibm.ws.logging.message.file.name=messages.log

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to block anything written to System.out from being written to your Liberty messages.log and console.log, set your traceSpecification in your server.xml's logging element as follows:

```
<logging traceSpecification="SystemOut=off"/>
```

Since you are using binary logging, you can also control what loggers are filtered out when running the binaryLog command as follows:

```
binarylog view daytrader3sample --excludeLogger="SystemOut"
```

By changing the traceSpecification you would avoid having the System.out content being added to your logs.  By using the filter on the binaryLog command you would just omit SystemOut from the binaryLog output without affecting what actually is stored in the logs.

Answer (score -2):

Login to WAS as the image below and set it to "No Logging":

[image]

Comment: This question is for WAS Liberty.  Not WAS Classic.

Comment: It is WAS Liberty what I have provided.

Comment: Hussan, thanks for your response. 
I have not a console like WAS in Liberty. Do you know how can I implement this using server.xml or other Liberty config file?
Thanks again.